# whois query against a list of urls

Tags: php, pear, whois

I am using PEAR's Net::Whois to look up WHOIS records. The following code is intended for a single domain query. I want to query more than one domain names by rewriting the code below. I have a URL list saved in .txt file (plain text). My question is that can I query these urls one by one and look up their WHOIS records by executing a single script? if yes, then please give me some hints how I can do that; which php functions are suitable to automate this task. Thank you.

```
require 'Net/Whois.php';

$server = 'whois.networksolutions.com';
$query = 'google.com';

$whois = new Net_Whois;
$data = $whois->query($query, $server);

echo($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that each line of file contains single domain. You need read this file, and call $whois->query in loop:

```
require 'Net/Whois.php';

$server = 'whois.networksolutions.com';

$whois = new Net_Whois;
foreach (file('query-file.txt') as $query) {
  $data = $whois->query($query, $server);

  echo($data);
}
```

Comment: 1) use the registry whois server (`whois.verisign-grs.com`), not one of the registrars one and 2) be aware of the TOS, you will get rate limited or blackholed if you bulk query it